# Get the and set the width of each div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center the div's in the li, the issue is that the div's content is generated dynamically and could be longer or shorter.

here is a sample of one li (there are at least a few of this up to about 1000)

```
<li class="row">
<div class="channel_date">
    <p class="channel">
        Returns | 
    </p>

    <p class="date">
        Mar 11, 2014
    </p>                

</div>  
</li>
```

So i need to get the width of the of each div after the page loads and set the div to that width so margin auto would center it. best if it could be done with jquery Thanks your answer would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Can you share with us the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: couldnt get anything close to working so didnt post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through every matching div and get the current width. Then apply that same width to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.channel_date').each(function() {
        var curWidth = $(this).width(); // determine the width
        $(this).width(curWidth); // set the width
    });
});
```

Then in CSS:

```
.channel_date {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but sets all divs to the width of the widest div, not each individual divs own width?

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient information to help me debug that problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin use for center in window, you can change it to your own

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

How to use :

```
$(element).center();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably best to use the document ready function of jQuery and set the widths of the divs - see: http://api.jquery.com/width/